# How to fix "UnsatisfiedLinkError"

Tags: java

I'm trying to create Java software that allows me to start a program and control it through ActiveXComponent. In order to use ActiveXCompnent I downloaded a JAR file named "jacob-1.18". When I am in runtime and I try to start the program this exception occurs:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jacob-1.18-x64 in java.library.path

How can I solve this problem?

I tried to follow this solution but the error remains:
[UnsatisfiedLinkError with JACOB and jre 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15941234/unsatisfiedlinkerror-with-jacob-and-jre-1-7)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnsatisfiedLinkError with JACOB and jre 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15941234/unsatisfiedlinkerror-with-jacob-and-jre-1-7)

Comment: I tried to follow this solution but the error remains

Comment: include the path of your jar file into the CLASSPATH variable